# SharePoint 2010 use SPServices to get a users ID

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I'm using SharePoint with the SPServices jQuery library, and I'm making use of the `SPGetCurrentUser` function. However, it seems it just returns the login user name without the ID. Example:

`DOMAIN\user`

I need the whole account name with ID:

`1;#DOMAIN\user`

If there's a way just to return the ID I can concatenate the two together. But I can't find it.

Ultimately I'm trying to assign a list item to the current user. If there's a way to do this without the ID I'm open to that possibility as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok I figured it out:

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetUserInfo",
    async: false,
    userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).find("User").each(function() {
            curUserId = $(this).attr("ID");
            curUserName = $(this).attr("Name");
            curFullUserName = $(this).attr("ID")+";#"+$(this).attr("Name");
        });
    }
});
```

This little function will create three vars:

- curUserId = the current users ID (Ex: 1)
- curUserName = the current users Name (Ex: DOMAIN\user)
- curFullUserName = the ID and Name combined in SP format (Ex: 1;#DOMAIN\user)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I spent hours trying to implement a solution similar to what vvk put below. I always received a blank string. I found this solution right before I was about to give up on the whole thing. Works like a charm!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
 $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
        fieldName: "ID"
    });
```

Comment: Tried that, I just get a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(xData.responseXML).find("PropertyData > Name:contains('Name')").each(function() {
Name = $(this).parent().find("Values").text();
alert(Name);
});
```

[Please click here more details](http://peakfinders.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-get-login-user-id-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

Building on skinneejoe's answer which will return the ID of the current user; to find the ID for other users based on their login info (i.e. domain\username), just add the following logic:

```js
function getUserIdByUsername(login) {
    var user = {};
    var params = {
        operation: "GetUserInfo",
        async: false,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).find("User").each(function () {
                user.curUserId = $(this).attr("ID");
                user.curUserName = $(this).attr("Name");
                user.curFullUserName = $(this).attr("ID") + ";#" +
                $(this).attr("Name");
            });
        }
    };

    if (login != null) {
        params.userLoginName = login;
    } else {
        params.userLoginName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser();
    }

    $().SPServices(params);

    return user;
}

getUserIdByUsername('DOMAIN\\User')
```

Note: Userlogin should match the format 'DOMAIN\\User', note the second escaping backslash.